# As an Indian Citizen, can I use my b1/b2 visa after f1 visa period or will I have to leave US and reenter?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas, transition-of-visa-status

I am from India.I intend to travel to the US for a student clinical elective at a university in Texas for the months of November and December. The university will help me obtain an F-1 status. However, I want to attend a few conferences and educational seminars which are being held in January and february for which I will be using a B1/B2 visa which I already have expiring in 2023.

Will I have to leave the US and come back in January using a B1/B2 visa, or is there another way to change my visa status, or should I apply for both visas again.

Comment: @MarkMayo The title matches, but the answer to that question doesn't answer this one.

Comment: @AdityaSomani adjusted his question title to more accurately reflect. Feel free to add if you think anything can make it cleraer.

Comment: Even the content of this sounds suspiciously like http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/as-a-canadian-citizen-f1-visa-to-a-b1-b2-will-i-have-to-leave-the-us-and-re-en Are 2-month "student clinical elective at a university in Texas", followed by 2 months of "a few conferences and educational seminars" really that popular?

Answer (score 2):

If on your F1 entry you get an I-94 with a specific date on it (actually you won't get a paper I-94 these days (you can get it online), but they will also stamp the date next to your entry stamp), then you will need to leave the U.S. by that date or have filed a Change of Status by that date. Note that a Change of Status may not be approved.